# Rust: Wrapping a BufRead in Mutex while still implementing BufRead

Tags: rust

I need to construct a type that I can pass to the following function from a library.

```
pub fn read_write_pair<R, W>(read: R, write: W) -> Term
 where
   R: BufRead + Debug + Send + 'static,
   W: Write + AsRawFd + Debug + Send + 'static,
{
 // details elided...
}
```

Furthermore I want to be able to manipulate the `read` and `write` for my tests. Specifically, I want to be able to construct the two instances without any content, pass them to this function, and then letter set what the library will read and extract what it has written.

This is how far I have gotten for the `Input` type that will be used for the `read` side:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Input {
    prepared_content: Arc<Mutex<Cursor<Vec<u8>>>>,
}

impl Clone for Input {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        Self {
            prepared_content: Arc::clone(&self.prepared_content),
        }
    }
}

impl Input {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            prepared_content: Default::default(),
        }
    }

    fn append(&mut self, content: &str) {
        let mut cursor = self.prepared_content.lock().unwrap();
        cursor.get_mut().extend_from_slice(content.as_bytes());
    }
}

impl Read for Input {
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> std::io::Result<usize> {
        self.prepared_content.lock().unwrap().read(buf)
    }

    fn read_exact(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> std::io::Result<()> {
        self.prepared_content.lock().unwrap().read_exact(buf)
    }
}

impl BufRead for Input {
    fn fill_buf(&mut self) -> std::io::Result<&[u8]> {
        let mut content = self.prepared_content.lock().unwrap();
        content.fill_buf()
    }

    fn consume(&mut self, amt: usize) {
        self.prepared_content.lock().unwrap().consume(amt)
    }
}
```

From the inside out:

- `Vec<u8>` is the content to be read
- `Cursor` makes it a `BufRead`
- `Mutex` allows inner mutability for when I want to add more content to be read. It also makes the type `Send` and `Sync`
- `Arc` lets me have multiple owners - my test function and the library itself.

The problem comes with `fill_buff` from `BufRead`: it returns a `Result<&[u8]>` which would outlive the MutexGuard itself. A `Cell` would give me the same interior mutability, but it's not Send/Sync and I doubt a `Cursor` is Copy.

Are there any other strategies I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fundamentally not possible to get an `&[u8]` to a shared interior-mutable buffer, since that would allow mutation while an immutable reference exists. (As an example of something right on the boundary of this rule: [`Cell::get_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html#method.get_mut) allows getting a reference but requires `&mut` to the Cell, which thereby ensures the Cell is *not currently shared.*)

The simple thing that comes to mind is to, instead of implementing `BufRead` for `Input`, pass a `BufReader<Input>`. Then you can still externally provide bytes to read but you are not responsible for the buffer. However, this might read ahead too much. If that doesn't work for you, you will have to implement `BufRead` using a buffer which is *not* interior mutable — that is,

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Input {
    prepared_content: Arc<Mutex<Cursor<Vec<u8>>>>,
    buffer: Vec<u8>,
}
```

and the implementation transfers bytes from `prepared_content` to `buffer` as needed.

This approach means you cannot swap out the contents of the buffer from the test code, but you also *shouldn't* do that, because it violates the reasonable expectation that a `BufRead` implementation will leave the buffered bytes it has presented unchanged until the caller is done with them (by calling `consume()`).

Comment: Thank you! I went with a `BufReader<Input>` and it worked like a charm.
I did have to relax some bounds on a fork of the library but that is good enough for me.